# How to make part of programatic UITableView text clickable?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a programatic UITableView. I want to make part of the text in one of the strings clickable. Is this possible to do?

```
var moreSectionItems = [(image:String, title:String, subtitle:String)]()
moreSectionItems.append((image: "clouds", title: "Clouds", subtitle: "See the beautiful CLOUDS"))
moreSectionItems.append((image: "Stars", title: "Stars", subtitle: "See the beautiful STARS")) 
sections.append((sectionTitle:"This is what you can see",sectionSubtitle: "See all the good things.",items:moreSectionItems))
```

In particular, I want to make the part of the subtitles that say "CLOUDS" and "STARS" underlined and clickable. Is it possible to do this? Because I would need an attributed string, but the tableview calls for a regular string.

Comment: Cells typically contain UILabel instances. Label's support attributed text. Cells can contain text views or text fields. They both support attributed text. So do some research on creating clickable links in labels, text views, and text fields and then see which works best in your table view.

Comment: what do u mean by `tableview calls for a regular string`. Basically in a tableviewcell you would have some sort of label. In your label you can use attributed string. Quick google search should give you some results.

Comment: you can enter an attributed string like this. label.attributtedText = *attributedString*

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `label.attributtedText` and `NSLinkAttributeName`

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-make-tappable-links-in-nsattributedstring

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Want to learn iOS? You should visit the best source of free iOS tutorials!")
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com", range: NSRange(location: 19, length: 55))

        textView.attributedText = attributedString
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL, options: [:])
        return false
    }
}
```